# How do I update multiple variables in Python at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm pretty new to Python, I have written a web scraper that gives me output from 8 different tables into 8 pandas data frames. I am renaming the column names from each dataframe and extracting only 2 of those.

```
            df1.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df2.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df3.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df4.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df5.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df6.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df7.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            df8.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

            df_delvol1 = df1[["E", "F"]
            df_delvol2 = df2[["E", "F"]
            df_delvol3 = df2[["E", "F"]
            etc

            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('options_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%d %b %y')), engine = 'xlsxwriter') 
            df_delvol1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
            df_delvol2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
            etc
```

It works but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you place all your dataframes in a list you can then iterate through them and apply the same operation.

It would look something like this, in the first line I am just creating some random dataframes.

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 8))) for _ in range(8)]

for df in dfs:
    df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

df_delvols = [df[["E", "F"]] for df in dfs]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('options_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%d %b %y')), engine = 'xlsxwriter')

for n, df_delvol in enumerate(df_delvols):
    df_delvol.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet{}'.format(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an idea for avoiding redundant code -

```py
a = [1,2,3]
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(a)
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(a)
for var in ['df1.columns', 'df2.columns', 'df3.columns']:
    exec("%s = ['A']" % var)
```

```
>>> print(df1.columns)
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

I have explained it for only one column - 'A' but you get the point.